# Операторы препроцессора # и ##

Tags: c++

Для чего они нужны и как их использовать ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

# размещенный перед аргументом макроса превращает его в строку.
Например код:

```
#define QUOTE(a) #a

int main() {
    cout << QUOTE(2 + 2) << " = " << 4 << endl;
}
```

после работы препроцессора превратится в

```
int main() {
    cout << "2 + 2" << " = " << 4 << endl;
}
```

Полезный пример использования - отладочный макрос ASSERT.
Пример реализации:

```
#define ASSERT(c) \
    if (!c) { \
        std::cerr << "Assertion failed in " << __FILE__ \
                  << "(line " << __LINE__ << ") : " << #c << std::endl; \
        exit(1); \
    }
```

Если его передать ему ложное условие, например ASSERT(2 * 2 != 4),
то он выведет нечто вроде:

```
Assertion failed in test.cpp(line 12) : 2 * 2 != 4
```

и завершит работу программы.

## нужен, чтобы склевать аргументы макроса с другими частями макроса или друг с другом. Применяется он редко, в основном для кодогенерации. Пример из википедии:

```
#define MYCASE(item,id) \
    case id: \
       item##_##id = id;\
    break

    switch(x) {
        MYCASE(widget,23);
     }
```

После препроцессинга превращается в:

```
switch (x) {
    case 23:
        widget_23 = 23;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

В начале строки # означает собственно начало директивы препроцессора. 
В середине директивы она вот что обозначает. Дело в том, что если макрос находится внутри кавычек, замены не происходит. Если же нам нужно заключить макрозамену в кавычки, можно написать:

```
#define macro(a)  puts(#a)
```

Строка

```
macro (text);
```

будет развернута так

```
puts ("text");
```

Два знака ## произведут при развертывании конкатенацию фактических параметров макроса:

```
#define macro(a, b)  a##b

macro (name, 1)
```

развернется в

```
name1
```

См. K&R  гл. 4.11.2

Answer (score 1):

Примерно [так](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/10/1010.htm).

Директивы препроцессора:

```
#define CONSTANT value //определение константы
#include file_name     //включение в проект файла file_name
#pragma  option        //задаем машинно-зависимые опции(опции компилятора)
#define CONSTANT(paaram1) definition   //определяем макрос
#ifdef CONSTANT        //включает дальнейший код, если константа ОПРЕДЕЛЕНА
#ifndef CONSTANT       //включает дальнейший кот только если константа НЕ определена
#else        //используется с двумя предыдущими. Включает или исключает дальнейший
//код в зависимости от выполнения условия пред. раздела
#endif //конец условно включаемых/исключаемых фрагментов кода
```

Примерно так...

**UPD:** Оператор ## используется очень нечасто, так что за него можно и не думать...

Comment: Он и применяется нечасто потому что о нем не думают. И речь о операторах а не о директивах.

Comment: Речь идет об их ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИИ! Разве кто-то может описать оператор без приведения примеров использования? Бред какой-то...
UPD: не просто описать, а ПОНЯТНО описать!

Answer (score 1):

Пример использования ##:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    #define _W(x) w##x
#else
    #define _W(x) x
#endif
```

Теперь _W(string) будет раскрыт или в wstring, или в string в зависимости от поддержки юникода. Конечно, для строки лучше объявить соответствующий тип, но для каких-то функций/классов с префиксом w подобный макрос может пригодиться.