# Как разворачивается данный макрос?

Tags: c++, c, макросы, macro

Выполняя задачу по макросам попался документ о конкатенации макросов. В нем следующий код:

```
#define COMMAND(NAME)  { #NAME, NAME ## _command }
```

Макрос NAME ранее определен не был. Но, тем не менее, он воспринимается и работает.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает, потому что очень интересна данная конструкция, можно найти ей применение в дальнейшем.

Comment: Здесь COMMAND это имя макроса. Про остальное читайте тут:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39865/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8

Comment: Я читал этот вопрос и не нашел там ответа на свой. Я понял, как работает ##, но не понял объявления макроса внутри другого макроса и разделительной запятой.

Comment: А так (Если не понятно, то могу расшифровать): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682821/quote-a-c-macro-parameter

Comment: В примере именно тот текст из документа, который и навел на вопрос. Не понимаю, что делает запятая. если #NAME просто преобразовывает аргумент в строку, то почему вместо запятой не добавить ## _command?

Comment: В фигурных скобках инициализируются поля структуры command

Comment: Что значит "Макрос NAME ранее определен не был"? Это же параметр макроса COMMAND.

Comment: @AnT сбило с толку написание большими буквами и последующее использование с решетками и без, теперь разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример взят вот [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682821/quote-a-c-macro-parameter)

```
 // Макрос COMMAND служит для более короткой записи инициализации структуры command
 // Например результат следующих записей одинаков: 
 // COMMAND(name);
 // command c = {"name", name_command};


 #define COMMAND(NAME)  { #NAME, NAME ## _command }

 struct command // Структура для хранения некой комманды
 {
   char *name;
   void (*function) (void); // указатель на функцию
 };

 // инициализация массива комманд 
 struct command commands[] =
 {
   COMMAND (quit), // Команда quit
   COMMAND (help), // Команда help
   ...
 };

 // Предыдущую инициализацию компилятор "превратит" вот в это
 struct command commands[] =
 {
   { "quit", quit_command },
   { "help", help_command },
   ...
 };
```